# Dynamically create Jquery Mobile Navbar from JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm trying to dynamically create a navbar from data i fetch from a web api serving json data. Here's the code: https://gist.github.com/2962277
If i use:

```
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="a.html">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="b.html">Two</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

directly in html code works fine, but this is not what im looking for. I want to be able to create the list elements from the data in the like the code in gist show. Anyone could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Saw somewhere something about .trigger('create') to add Jquery Mobile to dynamically added elements but not sure how to use it.

Comment: What issues are you currently having with your present approach?

Comment: The Jquery Mobile styling is not loading, its just loading the elements but not with classes that jquery mobile adds to the elements for the styling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have concocted your HTML for the navbar widget, you simply call `.trigger('create')` on the widget:

```
var myNavbar = $('<div data-role="navbar"><ul><li><a href="a.html">One</a></li><li><a href="b.html">Two</a></li></ul></div>');
$('#some-container').append(myNavbar).trigger('create');
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Jde95/

This will trigger jQuery Mobile to initialize the widget.

For Example:

```
var url = "http://23.21.128.153:3000/regions.json";var jsonresults;
$.getJSON(url,function(data){
    var output = [];
    $.each(jsonresults, function(i,v){
        output.push('<li><a href="' + jsonresults[i].link + '">' + jsonresults[i].name + '</a></li>');
    });
    $('#main-content').append('<div data-role="navbar">' + output.join('') + '</div>').trigger('create'); 
});
```

Notice how I concocted the HTML, and used the `.append()` function.

Comment: Thanks, I don't see the .trigger('trigger') in the example. Where i'm supposed to put that? I mean used your example and I'm getting the same result, the list without the Jquery style applied.

Comment: I updated the answer, just call it on the element you are adding the HTML to, if that gives you a hard time then do this: `$('#main-content').append(...).children().last().trigger('create')`.

Comment: This somewhat worked, but only on the <a> element, jquerymobile added a class called ui-link but the elements style on ul and li still not loaded. Do you want me to update the gist with my current code?

Comment: I tried that locally and my browser gives me this warning. 2 event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future. Worked fine in jsfiddle.

Comment: I got it, ty very much. I had to do trigger('create') on the parent element. $('#main-content').trigger('create');

Comment: This worked for me. I was adding my  navbar to footer. So inside the div with data-role="footer", I added another empty div saying class="abc". The I appended the navbar code in js to the abc div and called trigger('create'); It worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem (I'm regenerating my navbar all the time, depending on the fetched data) and my solution has been the following:

```js
var navBar = '<div id="invNavBarAction" data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="left"><ul>';
navBar += '<li>MANY LINES AS YOU NEED</li>';
navBar += '</ul></div>';
$('#invNavBarAction').remove();
$('#invNavBarContainer').append($(navBar));
$('#invNavBarAction').navbar();
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="invNavBarContainer">
    <div id="invNavBarAction" data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="left"></div>
</div>
```